# Call function into view razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

Hi Can I call a function into my view to get the description of ids in the foreach

My view

```
   @if (Model != null)
            {
                int i = 1;
                foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                <tr class="">
                    <td class="left">@{ new Fullname().getfullname(item.student_id.value).ToString(); }</td>
                    <td class="left"></td>
                    <td class="left">@CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(item.paid_month.Value).ToUpper()</td>
                    <td class="left">@item.monthly</td>
                    <td class="left">@item.transport</td>
                    <td class="left">@item.discount_details</td>
                    <td class="left">@item.total</td>
                </tr>
                }
            }
```

in Fullname class

```
public class Fullname
{
    private dbEntities db = new dbEntities();
    public string getfullname(int? id)
    {
        var StudentSelect = db.student.Where(s => s.student_id == id)
            .Select(s => new
            {
                FullName = s.lastname + " " + s.firstname
            });


        return StudentSelect.FirstOrDefault().FullName;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get the student fullname from the  @item.student_id in the Model

but nothing displayed

thanks

Comment: Set breakpoint on 'getfullname' method and check if 'dbEntities' is able to connect to database. Also if you want to do it nicely consider using javascriptt for frontend, and server-side (C#) only to return raw data. Razor is nice, but overusing it will cause project to be unmaintable

Comment: Should work in principle (if you set up the DB connection correctly). Cleaner and faster way would be to add a property for `FullName` to the items and populate it when the rest of the item data is loaded, i.e. in the controller.

Comment: I set a breakpoint on fullname and it returns correctly but on the view nothing happed
I think I'm missing something in the call function in the view

Comment: Change all database calls to your controller and then return in your model.. this is why you use "Model, View and Controller"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you retrieve the Fullname correctly, but you never emit it as string into the rendered view.

Use the `@variableName` syntax to emit the value of a C# variable as string:

```
@{ var fullname = new Fullname().getfullname(item.student_id.value).ToString(); }
<td>@fullname</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

In MVC the interaction take place between model to view and vice-versa. To move in-between we require some event to take place and then it is processed through ajax or through form submit. Here, you are trying to reference a class function after you are returned from some controller which means that no event is triggered therefore no call is made to that function and no data is returned. But still to be sure as you can put a break point on your function and check whether the control is coming to it or not.

Comment: I don't this is correct. The Event that triggered the rendering has already happened in this case (e.g. a Get request that renders the View). While razor is rendering the View, we are still on the server side and can in principle make calls into the database. The `@{}` syntax encapsulates server side c# code.

Comment: @GeorgPatscheider....Thanks for enlightening me with that useful information. Learned something new because of you and El Hamza.